# Resolver este algoritmo o proceso?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, algoritmos

Estoy trabajando en un programa donde se gestionan pedidos y llevo 3 días atascado. Os pongo en antecedentes, los pedidos se guardan en una tabla de una base de datos, en cada registro se almacena el peso de ese producto de mayor a menor peso. Resulta que el pedido hay que agruparlo en cajas que no pueden pesar más de 35 kg y el peso de debe repartir entre las cajas de forma más o menos equitativamente.
Lo mejor es exponer un ejemplo. Imaginad que el pedido tiene 4 item y cada uno tiene un peso diferente. El peso total son 45kg por lo que se necesitaran 2 cajas.
He estado trabajando con la siguiente lógica. Divido el peso total entre 2 por lo que el peso medio de cada caja es de 22'5 kg.
A partir de aquí no se cómo plantearlo para agrupar el pedido en esas dos cajas. Comentar que el lenguaje que utilizo es C# y SQL Server. No se si es mejor trabajar los datos mediante cursores o traer los datos mediante un array al programa.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Hola, lo primero que te digo es que utilizar cursores generalmente no son una buena práctica pensando en la performance. También creo que C# permite manipular la información de una manera más simple y con más opciones. Dicho esto,  creo que el proceso seria dividir en la cantidad de cajas a completar y ordenar los productos por peso de menor a mayor y con esta lista ir sumando un producto por cada caja para ir completando

Comment: Muchas gracias por la contestación. El problema está en que se puede dar el caso de que al empezar con los más pequeños luego llegue alguno grande que pase del peso medio y lo deje fuera. ¿No? En cambio si se empezase por los de mayor peso luego se podría rellenar con los más pequeños pero ¿cómo podría hacer para itinerar una y otra vez hasta que termine con todos los items y agrupar los items en cada caja? ¿Los guardia en un nuevo array o iría actualizando la base de datos continuamente?

Comment: En el caso de que comiences por los más grandes vas a llegar a un punto donde el siguiente sea mayor. En ese momento deberías empezar a definir la lógica del proceso. Por ejemplo,  podrías seguir avanzando de caja para ver si es posible ingresar en la segunda y así sucesivamente hasta terminar con el listado de cajas y productos. Todo este proceso debería ser un proceso en memoria pero entiendo que transaccionado y una vez finalizado impactar en la base de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posible solución es tratar de colocar siempre los productos más pesados en las cajas que tienen más disponibilidad, en iteraciones hasta lograr colocar todos los productos.

Esto se puede hacer en cualquier lenguaje, siempre que hayas logrado idear el algoritmo para realizarlo. A manera de demostración, he preparado un ejemplo en SQL Server, que hace más o menos lo que he descrito.

Primero, una tabla para *simular* el pedido, con algunos datos, por ejemplo:

```
create table #pedido (
    idPedido      int not null identity (1, 1) primary key
  , articulo      varchar(30) not null
  , peso          numeric(15,5) not null
  , NumeroCaja    int
);

insert into #pedido (articulo, peso)
values ('jabon', 17.2)
     , ('shampoo', 8.4)
     , ('pasta dientes', 10.7)
     , ('detergente', 11.9)
     , ('café', 7.5)
     , ('chocolate', 6.2)
;
```

```
set nocount on;
declare @pesoMaximoCaja numeric(15,5) = 35;
declare @numCajas int;
declare @caja table (numCaja int not null, peso numeric(15,5));
declare @seContinua bit;
declare @hayPendientes bit = 1;

select @numCajas = ceiling(sum(peso)/@pesoMaximoCaja) from #pedido;

while @hayPendientes = 1
begin
    set @hayPendientes = 0;
    set @seContinua = 1;
    with n as (select row_number() over (order by (select null)) n from sys.all_columns)
    insert into @caja select n, 0 from n where n <= @numCajas;

    while (@seContinua = 1)
    begin
        with
        Resumen as (
        select NumeroCaja, sum(Peso) peso
          from #pedido
         where NumeroCaja is not null
         group by NumeroCaja
        )
        update c
           set peso = Resumen.peso
          from @Caja c
               inner join Resumen on Resumen.NumeroCaja = c.numCaja;

        with
        Pendiente as (
        select idPedido, NumeroCaja, peso, row_number() over (order by peso desc) orden
          from #pedido
         where NumeroCaja is null
        )
        ,
        Espacio as (
        select   numCaja
               , peso
               , @pesoMaximoCaja - peso PesoDisponible
               , row_number() over (order by @pesoMaximoCaja - peso desc) orden
          from @Caja
        )
        update Pendiente
           set NumeroCaja = Espacio.numCaja
          from Espacio  
               inner join Pendiente on Pendiente.orden = Espacio.orden
         where Espacio.PesoDisponible >= Pendiente.peso;

        if (@@ROWCOUNT = 0) 
        begin
          set @hayPendientes = 1;
          set @seContinua = 0;
          set @numCajas += 1;
          delete from @caja;
          update #pedido set NumeroCaja = null;
        end;
        if 0 = (select count(1) from #pedido where NumeroCaja is null) 
        begin
          set @seContinua = 0;
        end;
    end;
end;

set nocount off;
```

Con los datos de la primera corrida, y esta consulta:

```
select *, sum(peso) over (partition by NumeroCaja) PesoCaja
  from #pedido
 order by NumeroCaja, peso desc;
```

Obtenemos este resultado:

```
idPedido articulo          peso       NumeroCaja PesoCaja
-------- ----------------- ---------- ---------- --------
1        jabon             17.20000   1          31.80000
2        shampoo           8.40000    1          31.80000
6        chocolate         6.20000    1          31.80000
4        detergente        11.90000   2          30.10000
3        pasta dientes     10.70000   2          30.10000
5        café              7.50000    2          30.10000

(6 rows affected)
```

El algoritmo contempla el caso de que no logremos colocar los productos en la cantidad de cajas que estimamos originalmente, por eso tiene dos ciclos anidados. En caso de no conseguirlo, va agregando cajas una a una hasta que los logra colocar todos. Un caso fácil de probar es el que todos los productos pesen más de la mitad de la capacidad de cada caja, lo que haría imposible meter más de un producto por caja, pero que estén cerca de ese peso, para que la estimación original sea de pocas cajas y tenga que ir aumentando hasta acomodarlos todos, por ejemplo, con estos datos:

```
insert into #pedido (articulo, peso)
values ('jabon', 18.2)
     , ('shampoo', 18.4)
     , ('pasta dientes', 19.7)
     , ('detergente', 21.9)
     , ('café', 27.5)
     , ('chocolate', 19.2)
;
```

Obtenemos este resultado:

```
idPedido articulo          peso       NumeroCaja PesoCaja
-------- ----------------- ---------- ---------- --------
5        café              27.50000   1          27.50000
4        detergente        21.90000   2          21.90000
3        pasta dientes     19.70000   3          19.70000
6        chocolate         19.20000   4          19.20000
2        shampoo           18.40000   5          18.40000
1        jabon             18.20000   6          18.20000

(6 rows affected)
```

Considero que el resultado, para 60 o 70 líneas de código es **más que aceptable**, sin embargo no creo que esté listo para ir a producción (y francamente no creo que encuentres quien escriba eso por ti de manera gratuita).

Me viene a la mente algunos casos en los que este algoritmo podría fallar; habría que hacer pruebas e ir robusteciéndolo a medida que se encuentran esos *corner cases*, consideralo solo una demostración de que puede hacerse y, quizás, un enfoque inicial para desarrollar tu propia solución, aún así decidas hacerlo en c# u otro lenguaje en el que te sientas cómodo.

Creo que el algoritmo se auto-explica. Para dudas, observaciones, aclaraciones, nos vemos en los comentarios de esta respuesta.

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta. Esto me ha servido mucho. Como bien dices voy a seguir afinando pero estaba en blanco y no sabía como seguir. Un saludo